# How to know if the product qty is less than 10. Is there any alert in Magento 2.2.4?

Tags: magento2, product

How to show the notification in admin panel whenever the any one product's quantity is 0 as

**Dear Administrator, one of the product's quantity is going to 0**

How to get this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use default Magento settings `Notify for Quantity Below` under `Stores -> Configuration -> Inventory -> Product Stock Options`

To know more about it, you can go through

- https://docs.magento.com/m2/2.0/ee/user_guide/catalog/inventory-product-stock-options.html
- https://docs.magento.com/m2/2.0/ee/user_guide/catalog/settings-advanced-advanced-inventory.html
- https://docs.magento.com/m2/2.0/ee/user_guide/configuration/catalog/inventory.html